# Kotlin/Js add npm dependency from custom registry

Tags: kotlin, gradle, npm, kotlin-js, github-package-registry

I'm developing an application with Kotlin/JS and Gradle. I can easily add npm dependencies from the default npm registry with the `implementation npm("query-string", "7.0.0")` command.

However, I cannot add an npm dependency from a different npm registry like Github Packages.
I want to add [this](https://github.com/GitLiveApp/firebase-kotlin-sdk/packages/34606) npm dependency to my project. Without gradle I could just install the dependency by just using the command line and `npm install @gitliveapp/firebase-firestore` but this doesn't work with the gradle npm command. I also tried `implementation npm("@gitliveapp/firebase-firestore", "0.5.4")` but this produces the following error: `Couldn't find package "@gitliveapp/firebase-firestore@0.5.4" required by "project" on the "npm" registry.`.

How can I add npm dependencies with gradle from different registries other than the npm public registry.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js' version '1.5.10'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.5.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/kotlin/p/kotlin/kotlin-js-wrappers' }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-js'
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers', name: 'kotlin-react', version: '17.0.2-pre.212-kotlin-1.5.10'
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers', name: 'kotlin-react-dom', version: '17.0.2-pre.212-kotlin-1.5.10'
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers', name: 'kotlin-styled', version: '5.3.0-pre.212-kotlin-1.5.10'
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers', name: 'kotlin-react-router-dom', version: '5.2.0-pre.212-kotlin-1.5.10'
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers', name: 'kotlin-css', version: '1.0.0-pre.212-kotlin-1.5.10'
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers', name: 'kotlin-redux', version: '4.0.5-pre.212-kotlin-1.5.10'
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers', name: 'kotlin-react-redux', version: '7.2.3-pre.212-kotlin-1.5.10'
    implementation 'dev.gitlive:firebase-firestore:1.3.1'
    implementation 'dev.gitlive:firebase-auth:1.3.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.1.0"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0'
    implementation 'org.kodein.di:kodein-di-js:7.6.0'
    implementation npm("query-string", "7.0.0")
    implementation npm("firebase", "8.6.8")
    implementation npm("@gitliveapp/firebase-firestore", "0.5.4")

}

kotlin {
    js(LEGACY) {
        binaries.executable()
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.Kotlin2JsCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += '-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn'
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a sample `build.gradle` or `build.gradle.kts`

Comment: @FranciscoMateo I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do it via gradle now, see an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33496).
But you can create file `.npmrc` (or `.yarnrc`) in the project root and configure here (https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/npmrc.html)

Additionally see the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-project-setup.html#yarn):

> For example, to use a custom registry for npm packages, add the following line to a file called .yarnrc in the project root: `registry "http://my.registry/api/npm/"`