# Import local NPM package with Kotlin/JS Gradle plugin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, npm, kotlin-js

I want to import a local npm package into my kotlin project but I get the error `Can't add "convert": invalid package version "".`

File structure:

```
project
  - js
    - package.json
    - convert.js
  - src
  - build.gradle.kts
```

My `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("js")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(npm("convert", "file:../../../../wikimarkup-converter/js"))
}

configureKotlinJs()
configurePublication()
```

My path is correct, because it gives me another error when it's any different.

My `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "convert",
  "main": "convert.js",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

When I set a version `"1.0"` in my `package.json` I get the error

```
Can't add "convert": invalid package version "1.0".
```

in Gradle. So whatever version is in there is invalid.

I know there is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66546059/4161471), but it has no answers, and the issue is completely different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to import a JavaScript file in a Kotlin/JS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661122/is-it-possible-to-import-a-javascript-file-in-a-kotlin-js-project)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/68177037/4161471 https://stackoverflow.com/q/66546059/4161471